# Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Plugin class doesn't exist

Tags: magento2

I have created plugin of class 'Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer' and method of renderTitle() but it is showing error "Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Plugin class doesn't exist".

Here is my files like :
di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer">
        <plugin name="update_page_title" type="Namespace\Module\Plugin\Page\UpdateTitle" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

and plugin class

```
<?php     
namespace Namespace\Module\Plugin\Page;

class UpdateTitle
{
    public function afterRenderTitle(\Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer $subject, $result){
        return $result;
    }   
}
?>
```

Any one faced this type of issue any solution ..?
I have tried everything like delete generated folder run setup:upgrade commands etc..

Thanks

Comment: Its working fine for me in 2.2.5 version

Comment: can you run php bin/magento setup:di:compile then check ?

Comment: thank for your comment, okay let me check with this command also i am using 2.2.5 version.

Comment: Did it help @hardik ?

Comment: Hi, still its not working ..

Comment: Also i have checked into default setup, there is also not working same error..

Comment: can you share working zip any where so i can check it ..?

Comment: @Harik Patel have you getting the solution of it becuase I am stuck with this issue.

Comment: Is relative class path `app\code\Namespace\Module\Plugin\Page\UpdateTitle.php`?

Comment: @DharmendraJadav Yes its working. I did mistake with module name. thank you .